# Concise way to say "increases with n or some term of n"

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology

I'm writing a thesis proposal and one of the systems involved has unknown complexity. It's not a focus of the proposal, but I wanted to include a line like this, as speculation:

> Presumably the complexity of each new connection scales with the number of rules.

Unfortunately I don't know if asymptotic complexity (space and time) will be O($\log{n}$), O($n$), O($n\log{n}$) or even O($n^{99}$). But I do doubt that it will be constant, so increasing $n$ will have some effect on it.

What is a good, **accurate** way to write this concisely? I'm asking here and not at [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) because the CS accuracy is essential.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with the current formulation. Is it not concise enough?

Comment: I'm concerned that writing it as "scales with the number of rules" will imply linear asymptotic complexity. You could say "scales with the square of the rule count" and I think it would imply polynomial complexity. Does that help to clarify?

Comment: @TomvanderZanden "Scales with" to me just implies that it's some function of the number of rules, not even necessarily an increasing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Presumably the complexity of each new connection is **an increasing function of** the number of rules."

But you don't mean complexity. Problems have complexity, algorithms have running time (or, more generally, resource usage), functions have growth rate.

Comment: Thanks, and small followup since I don't have the sentence yet. (probably better not to start a new question.) Which of those would be used to describe a router slowing down with many concurrent connections? Maybe more of an IT question. It's about load, I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure it really fits into the complexity theory model, so I think I'd just say soemthing like "performance decreases" or, hey, even "the router slows down": there's nothing wrong with using simple words to describe a simple situation.